# .jasper pdf no se ve igual ejecutandolo desde java

Tags: java, weblogic, ireport

Diseñe un reporte con ireport designer 5.6.0, pero no se ve de una manera desde ireport y de otra cuando se genera desde una app jsf, en un principio le agregue las fuentes de ireport al proyecto y solucionó el problema con las negritas, pero sigue saliendo muy diferentes los tamaños de letra, un ejemplo es un label que desde ireport se ve perfectamente centrado, pero desde Java no cabe el texto, sale mucho más grande

Answer (score 1, accepted):

encontre este post [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23934218/jasper-reports-font-size-issue-exporting-to-pdf) donde paso algo igual, teniendo en cuenta mi solucion es :
si desde java se usa el .jasper entonces el ireport designer debe ser 5.5.1 o anterior, si desde java se usa el .jrxml se debe usar el jasperreports-5.5.1.jar o anterior para compilar, al parecer el problema ocurre cuando se compila el reporte con 5.6**